# Why rails form adds submit text to query params

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

With rails 5.1.5

I have this in a view:

```
<%= form_for(:date_filter, method: 'get') do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field(:travel_date , value: @travel_date) %>
  <%= f.submit 'Time Travel now' %>
<% end %>
```

The genrated html is:

```
<form action="/games" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input value="2018-03-16" type="date" name="date_filter[travel_date]" id="date_filter_travel_date">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Time Travel now" data-disable-with="Time Travel now">
</form>
```

Everythins is working correctly but when I press submit I have this url

`http://localhost:3000/games?utf8=%E2%9C%93&date_filter%5Btravel_date%5D=2018-03-16&commit=Time+Travel+now`

Why utf8 and commit=Time+Travel+now are there?

How to remove it?

Comment: You should change the request method from `get` to `post`. Please read http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: Rails doesn't add the "commit=", that's how forms work. The value of all non-disabled inputs is included in the submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need to remove these two params from your form. These are creaed by rails `from_for` and `submit` tag.

utf-8 here to support Internet Explorer 5 and encourage it to use UTF-8 for all forms. For more clarification you can look at [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/25215d7285db10e2c04d903f251b791342e4dd6a#commitcomment-118076).

If to still want to remove utf-8 params, you need to create your own html form without using rails `form_for` helper.

Removing commit params is more easier. Just change your submit tag from:

```
<%= f.submit 'Time Travel now' %>
```

to

```
<%= f.submit 'Time Travel now', :name => nil %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I chose method get as it adds the form field to the url. Now I switched to method post as it's much better. but I'd like the  controller to redirect to http://localhost:3000/games?date=2018-03-14 How can I add query param to the returned url?

Comment: I managed to make it work the way I want. All I had to do is use the post method and in the controller method receiveing the call I do: `    redirect_to(games_url(date_filter: date_filter_params))
`